# How can I check if array has an objects in Postman

Tags: testing, postman, integration-testing

I have a response the array with objects like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "project one"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "project two"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "project three"
    }
]
```

Have can I check if my responsed array have an object     {
"id": 3,
"name": "project three"
} for example?
I am trying to check by this way but it didn't work:

```
pm.test('The array have object', () => {
    pm.expect(jsonData).to.include(myObject)
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pm.expect(jsonData).to.include(myObject)` works for String but not for Object. You should use one of the following functions and compare each property of the object:

- Array.filter()
- Array.find()
- Array.some()

Examples:

```js
data = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "project one"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "project two"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "project three"
    }
];
let object_to_find = { id: 3, name: 'project three' }

// Returns the first match
let result1 = data.find(function (value) {
    return value.id == object_to_find.id && value.name == object_to_find.name;
});

// Get filtered array
let result2 = data.filter(function (value) {
    return value.id == object_to_find.id && value.name == object_to_find.name;
});

// Returns true if some values pass the test
let result3 = data.some(function (value) {
    return value.id == object_to_find.id && value.name == object_to_find.name;
});

console.log("result1: " + result1.id + ", " + result1.name);
console.log("result2 size: " + result2.length);
console.log("result3: " + result3);
```

Use one of the ways while asserting in Postman.

Answer (score 1):

**you can validate this also using includes after converting it to string using JSON.stringify**

```
pm.expect(JSON.stringify(data)).to.include(JSON.stringify({
    "id": 3,
    "name": "project three"
}))
```

## Also you can use lodash function some/any:

```
pm.expect(_.some(data,{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "project three"
})).to.be.true
```

https://lodash.com/docs/3.10.1#some

**Note:** **Postman works in a sandbox and only below libraries are suported:**

https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/postman-sandbox-api-reference/#using-external-libraries

Comment: If you need a higher version of lodash than the provided global `_` object (which at the time of writing uses 3.10.1) you must require it manually: `var latestLodashVersion = require('lodash');`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `to.deep.include` syntax. In your case, it would look like this:

```js
pm.test('The array have object', () => {
    pm.expect(jsonData).to.deep.include({ id: 2, name: "project two" })
    pm.expect(jsonData).to.deep.include({ id: 3, name: "project three" })
    pm.expect(jsonData).to.deep.include({ id: 1, name: "project one" })
})
```